# Excel MATCH text but return a value to left or right depending on other text

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

I have a terribly inelegant formula to return a value from the left or the right of a string depending on the MATCH.  It works, but I am hoping that someone can help with making this a bit easier to read.
The general read of the formula is:

- If you find (`MATCH`) "*TestSpec;*"
- Then return the value to the Right of the semicolon
- Else, return the value to the Left of the semicolon
- Further: if the Value is not shown, then do nothing

My problems are:

- The `IF` statement by itself can only return either the LEFT or the RIGHT
- The `MATCH` statement returns a Boolean so it's not helpful in determining LEFT or RIGHT
- 2 `IFERROR` statements

Here's the Excel Formula in all it's glory:

```
=IFERROR( 
   IFERROR(
     IF(MATCH("TestSpec;*",Table1[@Tags],0), 
       RIGHT(Table1[@Tags],LEN(Table1[@Tags])-FIND(";",Table1[@Tags])-1)
     ), \*End IF no alternate value if false*
     LEFT(Table1[@Tags],FIND(";",Table1[@Tags])-1) 
   ), \*First Error Catch*  
 "") \*Second Error Catch*
```

Sample Input Values:

- Customer; TestSpec
- Report; TestSpec
- Charting; TestSpec
- ProgramOptions; TestSpec
- TestSpec; WeatherZone

Output should just show:

- Customer
- Report
- Charting
- ProgramOptions
- WeatherZone

Comment: Can you perhaps show some examples of the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TestSpec",[@Tags])),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@Tags],"TestSpec",""),";","")),"")
```

Comment: @Sam Sometimes it is simpler to remove the stuff you don't want, than it is to extract the stuff that you do.

Answer (score 0):

How about two simple substitutes -

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Table1[@Tags], "; TestSpec", ""), "TestSpec; ", "")
```

This works for all your condition

Comment: Aritesh - that's a great option but that allows tags that I don't want to be included.  I suppose I didn't say that, specifically in the question but I "TestSpec" is the key.